# How to prevent Hibernate 6 from auto-escaping backslashes in a LIKE query via Criteria API?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, hibernate-6.x

I'm migrating a Spring Boot 2.7 application to 3.0 which upgrades Hibernate from 5.6 to 6.1 and I'm experiencing an issue with JPA's Criteria API creating a `SElECT ... LIKE` query.

Given the following JPA `Predicate`:

```java
String searchString = "search string with escaped special chars \\% and \\_";
criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("myColumn")), searchString)
```

A query like the following is generated in Hibernate 5.6 / Spring Boot 2.7:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE lower(myentity0_.`MyColumn`) like ?
```

While Hibernate 6.1 / Spring Boot 3.0 generate a query like:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE lower(m1_0.`MyColumn`) like replace(?, '\\', '\\\\')
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.6.

Unfortunately this behaviour breaks my application, because I do some preprocessing on my search string which includes escaping the special characters `%` and `_` with `\%` and `\_` in order to be able to search for them. The backslashes are then double-escaped by Hibernate which unescapes `%` and `_`.

I figured out a workaround which uses a different escape character like `#` in my search string and propagates this one to the query via

```java
criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("myColumn")), searchString, '#')
```

but that feels inconvenient.

Is there a possibility to prevent Hibernate from auto-escaping the search string? Unfortunately I didn't find this behaviour mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc).

Answer (score 1):

This was done as part of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15736 and makes sure that the escaping behavior is consistent across all databases.
If you want `\` to be your escape char, then configure it as such by using

```
criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("myColumn")), searchString, '\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe a little late, but I had the same problem and found the following solution. You should rewrite your query the following:

```
criteriaBuilder.like(
   criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("myColumn")), 
   criteriaBuilder.literal(searchString));
```

I found the 'criteriaBuilder.literal()' method in the hibernate 6.3 documentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#criteria-queries